# Iterations of orbit integration in GapLy

Tags: python, astropy, orbit

I am performing an orbit integration using [GalPy](http://galpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orbit.html). I want to perform many orbit integrations (~1,000,000) by varying potential model and initial conditions of the orbit. For every orbit integration, I then wish to access the orbit in the observable coordinate system, eg. (RA, Dec, dist, pm_ra, pm_dec, vrad) in physical units like degrees, kpc, mas yr-1, km/sec etc. based on Sun's distance and velocity.

The `getOrbit()` method allows instantaneous access to the orbit but only in R, phi, z, vr, vt, vz coordinate system. There is an option to access orbit in observable coordinates like

```
ra = op.ra(i1)
dec = op.dec(i1)
mu_ra = op.pmra(i1)
```

that is, accessing ra coordinate of the orbit at time instance `i1`.

This means to access the entire orbit, I must iterate this line over entire orbit. This is very very expensive computationally. Given that I need to do it for 6 phase-space coordinates and for >100,000 orbits, the problem becomes way expensive.

Is there a faster way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run things like

```
ra=op.ra(i1)
```

for arrays of times (so i1 can be an array of times). Internally, array operations will be used, so should be fast.